# Crontab not working on specific time

Tags: cron

**a.sh** contains:

```
mkdir abc
```

I made it executable using:

```
chmod 777 a.sh
```

Then I configured crontab using:

```
crontab -e
```

And entered this line:

```
56 09 * * * /home/subir/Jarvis/a.sh
```

The `abc` directory is not created at that given time.

Which steps can I take to figure out why this does not work as expected?

Comment: What happens if you run `/home/subir/Jarvis/a.sh` from an interactive shell?

Comment: This is exactly the same as in [Crontab to make directory in Desktop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555317/crontab-to-make-directory-in-desktop)

Comment: Put all permission stills not running

Comment: You've got the `abc` directory in your home directory though, is that not where you want it? If so create it elsewhere.

Comment: Does *anything* in cron work? Maybe you aren’t in the `cron.allow` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that’s exactly how you created the file, you haven’t set execute permission on it. You missed out this:

```
chmod +x a.sh
```

You may wish to set a more specific mode, refer to `man chmod` for more details.

If you don’t want to make it executable for some reason, you can still run in cron it by invoking it with your shell interpreter, e.g.

```
/bin/bash /home/subir/Jarvis/a.sh
```

Amend to use you preferred shell.

Comment: If they used `chmod 777` on the file, it's most certainly executable. That is not the issue.

Comment: Agreed, though that info was not available when I answered.

Comment: Now I don’t know what to think ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: As in "[Crontab to make directory in Desktop](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/555317)", I suspect that the script is run, but that it creates the directory in a place where they don't expect it to be created (their home directory). The location of the script itself does not magically become the current working directory of the script. As to why they accepted your answer, your guess is as good as mine.